# What is a good text editor for the cloud?

Tags: text, cloud, text-editor

Hi everyone I am looking to do more work based in the cloud, so I have more flexibility and can use virtually any computer to do my work on. So, my question to you is what is a good text editor for the cloud?

I currently do my development on a mac using text mate. Is there anything remotely similar that anyone would recommend?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a joke...  Otherwise I don't understand.  What features could possibly make a text editor more useful for work that is "based in the cloud"?  (I don't even know exactly what that last phrase means, but it could just be my ignorance.)

Comment: A cloud based text editor is needed for Chrome OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla has developed a unique app called skywriter that seems to do the trick. http://mozillalabs.com/skywriter/

*Update*
I have since found the following.

- Code Anywhere - https://codeanywhere.net/
- Atom Write - http://www.atomwrite.com/
- Koding - https://koding.com

All provide good solutions Code Anywhere is my favorite thus far.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to edit text files in a cloud service like DropBox, I've recently discovered Draft https://draftin.com/

It combines a clear interface focused on writing, MarkDown support for formatting and connections to Dropbox , Google Drive, Evernote and Box. Any change on the document is automatically saved back to the service it originated from. I wrote about it here http://bit.ly/g-draft

Comment: This is also a great solution because it gives you versioning on the cheap. Assuming you are linked to Git

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an older post, but I wanted to chime in here:

As CarterMan mentioned, there is [Koding.com](http://koding.com/) which is really good. You can get private vms now and will shortly be able to access them via `ssh` and host private domains. Couple with their editor and community features, koding.com is a pretty cool project.

Second to that would be [Cloud9 IDE](http://c9.io). You can edit in the cloud and use the command line, though you will need to upgrade to get [all the premium features](https://c9.io/site/pricing/). One of the cool things about this project is you can [fork the repo](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/) and host it on your own machine if you like, [the process](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/wiki/Installation-and-Usage) took me about 5 minutes to get up and running.

Previously I noticed that both these projects had disconnect issues in the past but more recently they've both seemed to become more stable.